# Simple FSM question

Tags: formal-grammars, finite-automata

Considering this FSM:
[image: finite state machine]

Can someone explain me why the grammar is not:

1. $S \rightarrow aA$
2. $A \rightarrow aA \mid bB \mid \varepsilon$
3. $B \rightarrow bB \mid \varepsilon$

Why does A not have a transition to $\varepsilon$?

Comment: The grammar given by the FSM and the FSM don't agree. A grammar from the FSM picture would be $S \to \epsilon \mid a A ; A \to \epsilon \mid a A \mid b B ; B \to \epsilon \mid b B$. There are productions to $\epsilon$ for all final states (all in the picture).

Comment: There is an error in my manual then. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both grammars are wrong:
The first does allow String $b$, which is not accepted by the NFA, the second does not allow $\epsilon$, which is accepted by the NFA.

Note that some definitions of regular grammars don't allow renaming of variables, which makes the first grammar irregular. In the same way $\varepsilon$-transitions don't extend the expressive power of NFAs, renaming variables does not extend the expressive power of regular grammars.

So if the automaton is what you want (i.e. ensure that a word which contains a $b$, contains an $a$, too), just add $S \rightarrow \varepsilon$ to your second grammar. If the first grammar is what you want ($\{a\}^*\{b\}^*$) add $S{b \atop \rightarrow }B$ to your automaton and $S \rightarrow \varepsilon\mid bB$ to the second grammar.

Comment: The first one is copy paste of my AI manual..

Comment: The first one allows b, because B is double rounded

Comment: No: There has to be a path from $S$ only using $b$.

Comment: You are right, I think S and A from the automata should not be double rounded, in the first grammar.

Comment: No, that's fine, since $S\Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B \Rightarrow \varepsilon$. You should an an arc $S{\rightarrow \atop b}B$ or make either $A$ or $B$ an initial state.